Require users to go through Staging Ground as long as they have other questions there
Today I had the frustrating experience of trying to usher a question through Staging Ground, only to find out that the user in question had simply ignored the whole process and had posted the question on the main site.
I think it shouldn't be hard to prevent such actions by making the staging ground compulsory for new question as long as users have other questions in the pipeline there. There's a better chance of people noticing this undesirable behavior when questions enter through the same channel.

I'm pretty sure this was raised in one of the annoucements and confirmed it should be happening... If it was confirmed, this should also be a [[meta-tag:bug]]; let me see if I can find the comment/answer.

I've seen this more than once - askers get one of their questions in SG and then they simply post another one. It's a dice roll whether or not it enters SG and seems biased towards "not". So, it's a "winning strategy" to not deal with SG. Doesn't matter whether the asker had any feedback on their SG entry or not. I fully agree that shouldn't be the case.

During the beta here's (link for people with access) what the staff had stated "for the release, once a user is in the Staging Ground (at the outset if the MVP we won't be routing 100% in, but hope to work our way up to that fairly quickly), they won't get any questions directly onto the main site until they either have a published "successful" question or a few published "neutral" (not negative or closed) questions."

Apart from that we saw this scenario occur during the beta too, @AbdulAzizBarkat . I'd say this is most certainly a [[meta-tag:bug]] at this stage then. Thanks for finding; I'm glad I wasn't hallucinating.

Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat, Thom, tagged [bug] now.

To be honest, I don't feel like this being a bug because not all questions going into the SG is supposed to be a temporary thing. If we manage to get the all questions into the SG (idk how realistic this is), we wouldn't have this problem. But cases as you mentioned in your post were also annoying during the beta tests. There, i just raised a custom flag linking to the other post as the OP would be bypassing the system.

I've seen this and flagged it with a custom moderator flag. I called it "Staging Ground Evasion" and provided a link to the staging ground version of the post.

That evasion seems to be possible by design though, given that "until they either have a published "successful" question or a few published "neutral" (not negative or closed) questions". Or did this particular user account not have the necessary amount of promoted questions to fulfil that rather lenient requirement?

@Gimby In this case it was OP's only active question in SG. I think that users should be directed to SG as long as they have any question in SG that has a chance of getting published. I'm not sure though how long questions remain there when they don't come to some closure (closed, published, deleted).

It was indeed in the initial plans as described in the SG Beta SOT for users to be prevented from circumventing the SG by posting a new question. It's possible this plan has changed since that point in time given the change in personnel, but it would still be good to get clarification from a staff member.

Yep, I had also mentioned it as a Comment in another Thread on 'Meta', related to the 'SG', 10 days ago... I now routinely check if a User has not re-created a New Qt to bypass the 'SG' when they "strangely" don't follow up on a Require major changes or delete their Qt in the 'SG'.
